# How to display the entire row of sql statement in TDengine？

Tags: sql, tdengine

I want to view the table creation statement in TDengine, So I execute the following sql:

```
SHOW CREATE DATABASE
```

However, it didn't display the entire row. How do I need to adjust it?

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I think this is what you need.

```
SHOW CREATE DATABASE\G;
```